# Why doesn't the data is not displayed when going through the ability check?(rails,cancancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, cancancan

I want 3 user levels as Admin ,Manager,Customer in my rails application. So i've created a devise model as Users and added a migration to add the user role to it.So when a user is signed up it stores the users role(whether he is an admin,a manager or a customer). And in my application there are models and controllers for product,delivery,services. And I want to set access levels to each models.

So Admin have access to all models, controllers

Manager have access to Product, Delivery

Customer have access to Services

And i've written the Ability model as follows

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.roles == "admin"
      can :manage , :all
    elsif user.roles == "manager"
      can :read, Products, Delivery
    elsif user.roles == "customer"
      can :read, Services
    end
end
end
```

And in my product's show view i've the following code

```
<% if can? :manage ,@products%>

<h1>Products</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<p>     <%= product.name%>
<p>         <%= product.price %><br>
<p>    <%= product.qty %><br>

  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

But even i sign in as an admin i can't see the content .But when i remove the ability checking lines it can be viewed without having any issue.So i predict that the issue should be in the way that  have used authorization.
And My user model is as follows.

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

         ROLES = %i[admin manager customer]
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role)
end

end
```

And in views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
I've included the following code block.

```
<div>
    <%= f.collection_select(:role, User::ROLES, :to_s, lambda{|i| i.to_s.humanize}) %>
  </div>
```

This is what i have got to check the ability in my products/show view

```
<% if can? :manage ,@products%>

<h1>Products</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<p>     <%= product.name%>
<p>         <%= product.price %><br>
<p>    <%= product.qty %><br>

  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.roles` return an array and you are comparing array with string `user.roles == "admin"` which will always be `false`.

Instead use methods from `User` model like`user.role?(:admin)` to check the roles

So you ability should look like

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :manager
      can :read, [Product, Delivery]
    elsif user.role? :customer
      can :read, Service
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your controller you should have written something lie

```
class ProductsController < ActionController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
  ...
  end

  # and other resouceful actions
end
```

`load_and_authorize_resource` does lot of magic and one of them is load all the products on which `current_user`(devise user) has access to.

Now in view, you don't have to explicitly check `<% if can? :manage ,@products%>`. `@products` will have only products which the current user has access to.

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<%@products.present?%>
   <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <p><%= product.name %></p>
    <p><%= product.price %></p>
    <p><%= product.qty %></p>
  <%end%>
<%else%>
  <p>There are no products to display.</p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Updated the question little bit.Can you please improve your answer for me to get a clear idea.

Comment: @TharinduThathsarana hope the update answer can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much ..It helped me a lot

Comment: But in the cancancan documentation it says that it is possible if we are implementing one role per user.And it says that "It's then very simple to determine the role of the user in the Ability class."

can :manage, :all if user.role == "admin" .                                                                 https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

Comment: can you explain this a little bit.